# Custom Table with R Markdown v2 and ioslides

Tags: css, r, knitr

I'm doing a presentation with R Markdown v2 and ioslides. The font that I get in the tables by default is a little too small.

For example:

```
---
title: "Never put off 'till tomorrow?"
author: "Ignacio Martinez"
date: "09/23/2014"
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    incremental: yes
    css: ./styles.css
    logo: ./img/rotunda.png 
    widescreen: yes
    self_contained: true
    font-import: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu
    font-family: Ubuntu
runtime: shiny

---

## Estimates (OLS)

|                    |          Certificate|
|-------------------:|--------------------:|
|Took Quiz 1 on Day 1|          0.154\*\*\*|
|                    |          (0.003)    |
|Constant            |          0.006\*\*\*|
|                    |          (0.002)    |
|N                   |               23,463|
```

How can I increase the font size?

Comment: You can use a custom `styles.css` including something like `table{font-size: 16px;}`

Comment: Thanks! That does the trick. Is there a place where I can read what else I can change with styles.css? For example, I would like to make the font of the text I write after `>` bigger. I would also like to use Ubuntu as the default font. I added that to my yaml but is not really working

Comment: Did you find solution to your question?

Answer (score 7):

I don't like the colour scheme or spacing of the default CSS file, so I wrote this one.  It works in both ioslides_presentation and html_document.

```css
table,
.table-condensed,
table.rmdtable {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
table,
.table-condensed,
table.rmdtable,
table.rmdtable .header th,
.table > thead > tr > th {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-style: solid;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-width: medium 0 medium 0;
  border-color: inherit
}
table.rmdtable th,
table.rmdtable td,
table th,
table.rmdtable tr > td:first-child,
table.rmdtable .even {
  font-size: 100%;
  padding: 0.4em 0.5em;
  color: inherit;
  background: #FFF;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.table > tbody > tr > td {
  border-width: 0;
}
```

If you want to modify other things, you can examine the existing values and play with them in most browsers.  In Firefox, you right click on the thing you want to change, and choose "Inspect Element".  The source will pop up and the element will be highlighted; the active CSS is shown on the right.  You can deactivate parts of it to see what effect they have.